# Multivariable limit involving log in a point different than origin

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, logarithms

I'm having a hard time calculating the limit of

$$\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (1,2)} \frac{\log (1+x^2+y^2)}{4x^2-y^2}$$

If I substitute $(x,y)\to(1,2)$ I get

$$\frac{\log(6)}{0} = \infty $$

Can I say that it is equal to $\infty$ or that since it depends on the sign of $0$ then the limit doesn't exist (as if it is $0^+$ then it'd $+\infty$ and if it is $0^-$ then it'd $-\infty$)?

Comment: It doesn't exist is a more precise answer